# Animated background overflowing from DIV

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm trying to create a loading like effect and I'm not sure if this is the correct approach.

I'm trying to animate it from left to right but it's neither starting from the left nor it is ending in the right. It is overflowing out of the DIV. I tried with `overflow: hidden` and `left: 0` but that's not working either. Clearly, my approach is wrong or something's missed out. Kindly help out.

Here's what I have so far: [JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rxs2v4k9/)

```css
.timeline__story {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 15px;
}
.timeline__blank {
  position: relative;
}
.timeline__blink {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  animation: joey 3s ease-in-out infinite;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-65deg, transparent 0%, transparent 45%, transparent 48%, #A5C8E5 50%, transparent 52%, transparent 55%, transparent 0%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-65deg, transparent 0%, transparent 45%, transparent 48%, #A5C8E5 50%, transparent 52%, transparent 55%, transparent 0%);
  background: linear-gradient(-65deg, transparent 0%, transparent 45%, transparent 48%, #A5C8E5 50%, transparent 52%, transparent 55%, transparent 0%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 1;
}
@keyframes joey {
  0%   {left: 0; top: 0;}
  50%  {left: 50%; top: 0;}
  100% {left: 0; top: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline__story timeline__blank">
  <div class="timeline__blink">&nbsp;</div>
  <div>
       This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is that what you wanna do? -- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to create a loader but with a different animation effect as shown in my JSFiddle.

Comment: Can u pls tell the effect name?

Comment: Here are some more options -- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: Can you see the effect I made in JSFIDDLE? It's overflowing and trying to fix that. Not looking for other effects.

Comment: Yes got it. So right side overflow of effect you wanna remove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution, its not perfect, but it will give you a starting point.

I gave fixed width to `.timeline__blink`

And I made `left` value of the keyframe to -50px, to push it outside the box on the left side.

Also gave `overflow:hidden` to the `.timeline__story`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
}

.timeline__story {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.timeline__blank {
  position: relative;
}

.timeline__blink {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  animation: joey 3s ease-in-out infinite;
  background: linear-gradient(-65deg, transparent 0%, transparent 20%, transparent 30%, #A5C8E5 50%, transparent 60%, transparent 70%, transparent 0%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes joey {
  0% {
    left: -50px;
    top: 0;
  }
  50% {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -50px;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline__story timeline__blank">
  <div class="timeline__blink">&nbsp;</div>
  <div>
    This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.
    This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample
    text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. Made some minor changes and it's working perfectly. Thank You so much! Wasn't thinking of adding a negative value.

Answer (score 0):

***Note***: By using relative units, your animation will be better rendered on different viewports.

Try to add the following changes:

For **.timeline__story**

```
max-width: 100vw;
overflow: hidden;
```

For **@keyframes joey** animation

```
@keyframes joey {
  0%   {left: -45%; top: 0;}
  50%  {left: 45%; top: 0;}
  100% {left: -45%; top: 0;}
}
```

---

**Preview**:

```css
.timeline__story {
  max-width: 100vw;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.timeline__blank {
  position: relative;
}
.timeline__blink {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  animation: joey 3s ease-in-out infinite;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-65deg, transparent 0%, transparent 45%, transparent 48%, #A5C8E5 50%, transparent 52%, transparent 55%, transparent 0%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-65deg, transparent 0%, transparent 45%, transparent 48%, #A5C8E5 50%, transparent 52%, transparent 55%, transparent 0%);
  background: linear-gradient(-65deg, transparent 0%, transparent 45%, transparent 48%, #A5C8E5 50%, transparent 52%, transparent 55%, transparent 0%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 1;
}
@keyframes joey {
  0%   {left: -45%; top: 0;}
  50%  {left: 45%; top: 0;}
  100% {left: -45%; top: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline__story timeline__blank">
  <div class="timeline__blink">&nbsp;</div>
  <div>
       This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. This is a sample text. 
  </div>
</div>
```